# Follow-up notifications for comments posted on others' posts

Tags: discussion

When we leave comments on others' posts, we don't get the follow-up notifications unless we have been tagged. But I think that we should get the notifications even if we are not tagged so as to follow the conversation and contribute other things that we can.

Comment: You should get notifications unless somebody _else_ was tagged, in which case the system assumes that it's directed to that one person only.

Comment: Well, I believe we should get notification even when somebody else is tagged on the comment of the post where I had invested my arguments, so that I can follow-up. But along with that, there should be an option to *unfollow* from the post in case one feels it's no longer of one's interest. Many forums have such options.

Comment: @Ramit Comments aren't a forum, though, and aren't mean for discussion.  The chat rooms are, and if two people go back-and-forth enough, the system even tells you to go there and auto-generates a link.

Comment: Actually I didn't mean to convey *discussion.* I meant constructive inputs on the post.